# How to restrict to empty trashcan

Tags: alfresco

I would like to restrict emptying of trashcan by ordinary users. Permission to empty trashcan should have only users with admin role.

I have several ideas, but I'm not sure about their accuracy. For example to implement Java method used as evaluator before button displaying? Or any other sophisticated way, solution or implementation, how to secure this restriction?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should create share-extension. It is a sophisticated way to implement this.

Follow the below-given steps in share project to achieve this.

1. Add the following module at share-widgets.xml located at web-extension/site-data/extensions/

> ```
> <extensions>
> <modules>
> <module>
> <id>Customize Share header - remove 'Trashcan' button from user 
> menu</id>     
>   <version>1.0</version>    <auto-deploy>true</auto-deploy>      
>   <customizations>  <customization>
> <targetPackageRoot>org.alfresco.share.header  </targetPackageRoot>
> <sourcePackageRoot>org.alfresco.components.profile
> </sourcePackageRoot>
> </customization>
> </customizations>
> </module>
> </modules>
> </extension>
> ```

2. Create the folder structure under the site-webscripts as per the  : org/alfresco/components/profile
3. Copy the following file userprofiletoolbar.get.js from the installed Alfresco instance and place it at the org/alfresco/components/profile
4. Change the following line from the userprofiletoolbar.get.js

   // Add Trashcan link
    addLink("user-trashcan-link", "user-trashcan", "link.trashcan");

   to

   if(user.isAdmin){
    addLink("user-trashcan-link", "user-trashcan", "link.trashcan");
   }
5. Restart the server.